# How to load the ena driver on Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to load the ena driver on a Ubuntu VM.

According to the documentation, my VM has the `vif` low-performance driver:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-190:~$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: vif
version: 
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: vif-0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

However, I have already compiled and loaded the ena driver as explained [in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html) and [in the driver docs](https://github.com/amzn/amzn-drivers/tree/master/kernel/linux/ena):

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-190:~$ lsmod | grep ena
ena                    86016
```

Am I missing any steps here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If either `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids instance_id --query "Reservations[].Instances[].EnaSupport"` or `aws ec2 describe-images --image-id ami_id --query "Images[].EnaSupport"` (where `instance_id` is your (`i-e04566365f208b6584`) instance id and `ami_id` is your AMI's ID (`ami-6365f208`)) doesn't return "True" something is not marked as supporting ENA.

If it's your instance.  Stop it, and run `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id instance_id --ena-support` to enable support and restart it.  If it's your AMI, you'll either have to select an AMI that already has ENA support, or make your own from an instance that's been tagged (per above) as supporting ENA.

If your AMI already supported ENA, after running the above command, start it back up and `ethtool -i eth0` should show support.  If your AMI was the problem, you'll need to launch a fresh instance from an AMI that has ENA support.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#enhanced-networking-ena-linux

Note that even though it says the AMI is optional, I've found that not to be the case.  An AMI with support was required for me.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 18.04 AMI, fully up to date with the `5.3.0-1030-aws` kernel and with `linux-aws` installed. Both the instance and the AMI are reporting `[ true ]` for `EnaSupport`. And yet `ethtool -i eth0` keeps reporting `driver: vif`. Turns out, ENA is not supported on T2 instances despite this `true` claim.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#ena-requirements has a list of supported instance types.  While T2 isn't on the list, T3 & T3a instances are, if you can move to the newer specs.

Comment: In moving two instances from t2 to t3a I also had to create an AMI for one of them but not the other. As @PhilippeChaintreuil said, the AMI might not be optional for you.